# How to build a custom scaler based on StandardScaler?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a custom scaler to scale only the continuous variables on a dataset (the US Adult Income: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/adult-census-income), using StandardScaler as a base.
Here is my Python code that I used:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

class CustomScaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin): 
    
    
    def __init__(self,columns,copy=True,with_mean=True,with_std=True):
        
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean,with_std)
        self.columns = columns
        self.mean_ = None
        self.var_ = None
        
    
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.scaler.fit(X[self.columns], y)
        self.mean_ = np.mean(X[self.columns])
        self.var_ = np.var(X[self.columns])
        return self
    

    def transform(self, X, y=None, copy=None):
        
        init_col_order = X.columns
        
        X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(X[self.columns]), columns=self.columns)
        
        X_not_scaled = X.loc[:,~X.columns.isin(self.columns)]
        
        return pd.concat([X_not_scaled, X_scaled], axis=1)[init_col_order]

X=new_df_upsampled.copy()
X.drop('income',axis=1,inplace=True)

continuous = df.iloc[:, np.r_[0,2,10:13]] 
#basically independent variables that I consider continuous

columns_to_scale = continuous

scaler = CustomScaler(columns_to_scale)

scaler.fit(X)
```

However when I tried to run the scaler, I met this problem:
[image]

So what is the error that I have on building the scaler? And furthermore, how could you build a custom scaler for this dataset?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @AntoineDubuis, that `ColumnTransformer` is a better (builtin!) way to do this.  That said, I'd like to address where your code goes wrong.

In `fit`, you have `self.scaler.fit(X[self.columns], y)`; this indicates that `self.columns` should be a **list of column names** (or a few other options). But you've defined the parameter as `continuous = df.iloc[:, np.r_[0,2,10:13]]`, which is a **dataframe**.

A couple other issues:

1. you should only set attributes in `__init__` that come from its signature, or cloning will fail.  Move `self.scaler`
   to `fit`, and save its parameters `copy` etc. directly at `__init__`.  Don't initialize `mean_` or `var_`.
2. you never actually use `mean_` or `var_`.  You can keep them if you want, but the relevant statistics are stored in the scaler object.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create a custom transformer for this problematic. as this operation can be performed using `ColumnTransformer`. This transformer allows different columns of the input to be transformed separately.

The example below is scaling the columns `['A', 'B']` without changing the column `C`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(10), 
                 'B': np.arange(10),
                 'C':  np.arange(10)})


transformer = make_column_transformer(
    (StandardScaler(), ['A', 'B']),
    remainder='passthrough'
)

pd.DataFrame(transformer.fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns)
```

This output the following result:

```
          A         B    C
0 -1.566699 -1.566699  0.0
1 -1.218544 -1.218544  1.0
2 -0.870388 -0.870388  2.0
3 -0.522233 -0.522233  3.0
4 -0.174078 -0.174078  4.0
5  0.174078  0.174078  5.0
6  0.522233  0.522233  6.0
7  0.870388  0.870388  7.0
8  1.218544  1.218544  8.0
9  1.566699  1.566699  9.0
```

Comment: If the columns to be scaled aren't the first ones, `ColumnTransformer` will change the order; just be careful when setting the column names while re-dataframing.